# Xcode: import header by default

Tags: objective-c, xcode, import, header

Is there a way to import a certain header by default in a .m file each time it's created using Xcode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you could change the system file templates in

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode/Templates/File Templates/Cocoa Touch

Or you just import that file in your `ProjectName-Prefix.pch` so it will be known in every file..

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can import it into the pre-compiled header. `<AppName>-Prefix.pch`